# Impedir que uma aplicação seja fechada pelo usuário através do gerenciador de tarefas

Tags: c#, .net, processo

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que não pode ser fechada pelo usuário. Mas mesmo eu eliminando todos os meios de fechar a aplicação, inclusive por ela mesma, ainda é possível finalizar o processo pelo gerenciador de tarefas. Tem como impedir isso? É possível remover a aplicação do gerenciador de tarefas?

Comment: Sua pergunta está esquisita. Você quer remover ou que impedir que remova do gerenciador de tarefas?Ou o que você quer é impedir que o programa seja encerrado de alguma forma?

Comment: Outra questão que convém considerar, o utilizador que pode fechar o processo tem permissões de administrador?

Comment: Acho que ele só quer impedir do usuário finalizar o processo, porém o próprio processo pode se finalizar, tal como funcionam alguns antivírus (que rodam em um nível de acesso bloqueado).

Comment: Desculpa a confusão na pergunta, o usuário tem permissão de administrador e não quero que o usuário feche a aplicação.

Comment: Existe sim uma forma, use hooks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De uma maneira geral **isso não é possível**, especialmente por um código na sua aplicação. A aplicação em si não tem controle sobre isso.

O máximo que é possível é não dar privilégio de encerrar (`TERMINATE`) o processo quando instala o programa, mas não resolve totalmente. Ainda bem que nenhum software pode fazê-lo.

O usuário pode impedir que o software seja executado automaticamente na próxima inicialização e ele matará seu programa definitivamente de forma fácil. Portanto nem vale o esforço.

Se ele souber o que está fazendo é possível dar o privilégio por conta própria sem precisar dar um *boot* na máquina. Existem softwares especializados que matam processos que não podem ser mortos. O próprio [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da Microsoft pode ajudar fazer isto.

Certamente existem alguns artifícios possíveis como capturar o `NtTerminateProcess` no *kernel* ou criar um outro programa que fique monitorando este principal. Mas **nenhum truque é efetivo**. Pior é você achar que está protegido quando na verdade não está.

Esqueça essa ideia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou ver o que posso fazer a respeito.

Answer (score -1):

A solução que eu encontrei foi ficar verificando os processos e caso o usuário abra o gerenciador de tarefa eu o fecho. Fiz uma Thread para esse propósito.

```
        public void antiGerenciadorDeTarefas() {
            while (true) {
                Process[] processos = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process processo in processos) {

                    if (processo.ProcessName.Equals("Taskmgr")) {
                        processo.Kill();
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Primeiro isto não resolve o problema porque a pessoa pode matar o processo de várias maneiras diferentes inclusive ainda dá para mandar pelo gerenciador de tarefas. Depois você pode até ser responsabilizado por tentar burlar o funcionamento do computador que não é seu. Não recomendo fazer isto se não por motivos técnicos (esta solução traz outros problemas) por motivos éticos.

Comment: Não é anti ético dependendo do motivo, neste caso quero fazer uma tela de bloqueio estilo o de lan-house.